# How to get data from input type text that created by jquery in php

Tags: php, jquery

in my program user can create  by clicking on button (jquery). But php does not send data to another page.

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var counter = 2;
      $("#addButton").click(function () {
          if(counter>10){
              alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
              return false;
          }
          var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
                  .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
          newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>ویژگی '+ counter + ' : </label>' +
          '<input type="text" name="txt' + counter +
          '" id="textbox' + counter + '" class="form-control" style="margin:5px">');
          newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
          counter++;
      });
  });
```

php :

```
$x = 1;
while ($x<11)
{
    $name = 'txt' . $x ;
    if(isset($_POST[$name]) && $_POST[$name]!='')
    {
        object::object_Insert($_POST[$name],$s);
    }
    $x++;
}
```

Comment: why you are not using ajax into it

Comment: What did you try to send a variable? These two pieces of code seem completely independent. jQuery is not calling PHP in any way. You want to make an ajax request.

Comment: save the value to hidden field, and fetch server side

Comment: i have tried ajax. the php can not get <input> data that created by jquery